# SSH with X11 tunneling gives authentication error

Tags: x11, ssh-tunnel

I get the following error when trying to open X11 applications through an SSH tunnel (on windows via Xming as X server and git bash).

`X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication`

Or this error when trying to do the same via MobaXTerm

`MobaXterm X11 proxy: Unsupported authorization protocol`

The destination linux (where the X client apps are started) is a very old one (SuSe 11.4) with X11 7.6.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that the hostname was configured in `/etc/hosts` to belong to `127.0.0.1`.

WRONG:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost my-computer-name
192.168.0.123  my-computer-name
```

The solution was to remove `my-computer-name` from `127.0.0.1`.

But why did that happen?

The lib `libxcb` uses `getpeername` to find the address of the X11 server and looks up that address in the .Xauthority file. `getpeername` returns the address that has been used to `connect` the socket. A bit earlier in program execution, that address has been retrieved by calling `getaddrinfo` with the hostname from the `DISPLAY` environment variable.

`getaddrinfo` returns a linked list of addresses. If the first address is the remote IP, everything works. If the first address is `127.0.0.1`, it can't find the correct authorization cookie and authorization fails.